# How can I sum a list of numbers, which they're strings?

Tags: python, for-loop, sum

I have this code, in which we get info from a .txt file, that when I go through the .txt, and .split() them, I get a list with a format ["Party", "Gender", "Name", and 13 entries of numbers, in strings "" (for example: "1", "15", "3", etc)], I wanna add this info as a tuple in a list called distrito17.

```
data = open("votacion.txt", "r", encoding="UTF-8")
distrito17 = []
for infocandidato in data:
    infocandidato=infocandidato.split()
    total = #?
    distrito17.append((infocandidato[:3], total)))

return distrito17
```

I know I can use this form:

```
... for vote in infocandidato[3:]
        total+=int(vote)
```

And then add it to the list, but I was wondering if there is a way to use sum(), because I can do a sum(), which would help but the entries are strings, so I can't make a sum out of strings obviusly, but I have seen in some codes people use some kind of codes where:

```
sum(for i in infocandidato[3:], ... )
```

Or some sort, does anyone have a idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for

```
sum([int(i) for i in infocandidato[3:]])
```

Comment: damn you all are quick, thanks!